# Using FeatureDetector in OpenCV gives access violation

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I need to find and match feature points in stereo images. Therefore I want to compare the different Feature Detection algorithms that are supported in OpenCV 2.4.5. by passing "SURF", "SIFT", etc. to the function.

The code snippet:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

...

void DisparityAnalysis::detectKeyPoints(Mat1b leftImageGrey, Mat1b rightImageGrey, string algorithmName)
{
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create(algorithmName);
    detector->detect(leftImageGrey, keypoints_1);
    detector->detect(rightImageGrey, keypoints_2);
}
```

The error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x770b15de in DisparityAnalysis.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I've already searched for solutions and found this one: [Access violation reading in FeatureDetector OpenCV 2.4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516023/access-violation-reading-in-featuredetector-opencv-2-4-5) The difference I've recognized is, that they use cv::initModule_nonfree() at the beginning. But when copying it into my code it doesn't compile because the identifier isn't found.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for SIFT and SURF, you'll need the nonfree module, that is :

- include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
- call cv::initModule_nonfree() at the beginning
- link against opencv_nonfree2.4.x.lib

Comment: thanks @berak, because "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp" was missing, cv::initModule_nonfree() gave an error